# AJAX does not show image on the first request but does so on consecutive requests

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax

So i am having this strange issue. I am trying to have a loding spinner icon whilst the ajax request is made. However, the spinner is not showing for the first request (since page manual refresh) however it shows for all requests made after that. This is for when i load the spinner GIF from a local folder.

Strangely, when I provide this URL (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif) which I found on another SO post, it works every time, but for other URLs from the web or for local files it doesnt show the image on the first request. The ajax is getting executed as I can see the screen colour change through the style, but just the spinner doesnt show.Anyone have any ideas why? Below is the relevant code.

`body`

```
<body>
  ...

  <div class="modal" name="modal" id="modal"></div>

</body>
```

`script`

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document)
                .ajaxStart(function () {
                    $("#modal").show();
                })
                .ajaxStop(function () {
                    $("#modal").hide();
                });
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            //Submit Data
            $(".submit").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // get data ...

                $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        // data values
                    },
                    success:function(response){
                        // update cart and some other stuff
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

`CSS`

```
.modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 )
    url('../images/ajax-loader.gif')
    50% 50%
    no-repeat;
}

body.loading .modal {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by addin the image as an hidden image to the html. I assume the image was not loaded at the time of making the request through the css.